# Extract/Replace and Convert string in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, script, regex, find-and-replace, string

i have a file looking like this:

```
Line 207:       ["Mystic Scroll: Shock and Swarm"] = {
Line 297:       ["Mystic Scroll: Concentrated Solar Beam"] = {
Line 474:       ["Mystic Scroll: Taunting Smite"] = {
Line 902:       ["Mystic Scroll: Quick Exorcism"] = {
Line 1130:      ["Mystic Scroll: Extended Avatar"] = {
Line 1146:      ["Mystic Scroll: Hardy Shadow Word: Pain"] = {
```

and i want it to be converted to this:

```
        "Shock and Swarm", -- [1]
        "Concentrated Solar Beam", -- [2]
        "Taunting Smite", -- [3]
        "Quick Exorcism", -- [4]
        "Extended Avatar", -- [5]
        "Hardy Shadow Word: Pain", -- [6]
```

How can i do this?
(I cannot do it by hand, its about 3262 line to convert)

Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a python script within the PythonScript plugin.

If it is not yet installed, follow this [guide](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/17256/guide-how-to-install-the-pythonscript-plugin-on-notepad-7-6-3-7-6-4-and-above)

- Create a script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> New Script)
- Copy this code and save the file (for example format.py):

```python
import re

counter = 0

def format(match):
    global counter
    counter += 1
    return '"' + match.group(1) + '", -- [' + str(counter) + ']'
editor.rereplace('^[^:]+:\s+\["[^:]+:\s*([^"]+).+$', format)
```

- Open the file you want to modify
- Run the script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> Scripts >> format)
- Done

**Regex explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
[^:]+       # 1 or more any character that is not a colon
:           # a colon
\s+         # 1 or more spaces
\[          # open square bracket
"           # double quote
[^:]+       # 1 or more any character that is not a colon
:           # a colon
\s*         # 0 or more spaces
([^"]+)     # group 1, 1 or more non double quote
.+          # 1 or more any character
$           # end of line
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Worked, big thanks

Comment: @Derind: You're welcome, glad it helps.